# OpenCover shows 100% coverage with no valid tests

Tags: c#, nunit, opencover, nunit-3.0

To a visual studio solution with 6 projects (class libraries & wcf services) I add a new Test project with one test, with just one line Assert.AreEqual(1,1). OpenCover shows a 100% coverage (100% Sequence and 100% Branch).

```
OpenCover.Console.exe -target:"nunit3-console.exe" "-targetargs:Services.nunit" -register:user -skipautoprops -mergebyhash
```

Only when I instantiated a class from the other projects in the test the coverage dropped to 0.1 %.

So looks like if a dll is not loaded, OpenCover cannot calculate its code coverage.

Now the question is if a new class library is added and it is never instantiated in a unit test, Will OpenCover just ignore the dll while calculating the coverage metrics.

This is important because we have a distributed team and a developer might just create a class library and never write tests for it. It does eventually show up in code reviews, but can OpenCover be configured to detect this situation.

Comment: It seems that you need to go back to OpenCover's documentation. Meanwhile, in SharpDevelop the OpenCover integration is easier to use, http://community.sharpdevelop.net/blogs/mattward/archive/2012/08/08/CodeCoverageWithOpenCover.aspx http://community.sharpdevelop.net/blogs/mattward/archive/2014/07/27/BranchCoverageWithOpenCover.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So looks like if a dll is not loaded, OpenCover cannot calculate its code coverage.

This is expected behaviour

> Now the question is if a new class library is added and it is never instantiated in a unit test, Will OpenCover just ignore the dll while calculating the coverage metrics.

It doesn't ignore it, the runtime doesn't load the assembly and so OpenCover does not see it.

> It does eventually show up in code reviews, but can OpenCover be configured to detect this situation.

Not as it stands but you could write a test that tries to load every .dll in its folder. This will cause it to load and OpenCover will see it (assuming the pdb s available and the filters allow it etc etc)